# Notejs: How to convert incoming network packets to a stream object?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I've got some UDP listener in Nodejs that sends me video packets as 'msg' Buffer objects. How do I combine these into a stream object in memory, so I can later pass the stream object along to some stream readers, for example?

```
var udp = require('dgram');
var server = udp.createSocket('udp4');
server.on('message',function(msg, info) {
    // how to I write the incoming Buffer 'msg' to a stream object in memory?
});
```

Comment: Streams are meant to be more like pipes, where data is consumed as needed. If you plan to wait until you pass it along, would it not be better to buffer the data in an array for example?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://derpturkey.com/buffer-to-stream-in-node/

Comment: server.pipe(yourStream)

Comment: Igor Litvinovich, "server.pipe is not a function"

Comment: Pieter, it says "_read" method isn't implemented when I try to run the code they give... I'm using Node 10.16 btw.

Comment: I'm looking into memorystream npm now but I'm still not sure it's what I need.. I'll check